# Searching for a file inside HDFS using MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, filesystems, distributed, distributed-computing

I am very new to Hadoop and was wondering how to search for a specified file name inside HDFS using MapReduce? Let's say that I have thousands of terabytes of imaged-map data named by their latitude/longitude coordinates. Provided a given lat/long coordinate, how would I quickly find that file using MapReduce?

I searched around and found that one way was to pipe it to grep:

```
hdfs dfs -ls -R / | grep [search_term]
```

but this would be very slow for many files of big data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take:

1. It is not advisable to store too many files in HDFS. Check this link: [Namenode File No. Limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764493/namenode-file-quantity-limit)
2. Search using MR is not efficient. Especially if you data is not partitioned or indexed.
3. Your case would be best served by using a KeyValue store or a distributed search tool like Elastic Search (Given my limited understanding of your use case)