# In Hadoop, Is there any quotation between Metadata and actual data storage?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, metadata

Any formula exists in Hadoop as per below discussion?

Assuming that:

1Kb of Meta data means one liter (in water bottle)

Physically occupying one liter means we know the actual size(imagine water bottle)

Equation:

1kb Metadata = 1 litre bottle size (actual data storage)

Same like in Hadoop,

Meta data of 1kb occupies how much actual size in data node physically?

1kb Metadata = ? (actual data storage size)

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764493/namenode-file-quantity-limit

Comment: Thnks BruceWayne.